# How can I show the text of Text Button when I make it's onPressed function return Null ?(in dark mode)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying to create *an Onboarding view* with the **next** and **previous** `Text Button()` where when the user is in the first index of the Onboarding the **previous** button should be **unclickable**.

I already did it by making **onPressed: function** return **Null** when the onboarding current `index = 0` but the problem is the previous's **text** doesn't appear when I use **dark mode**. I hope someone can help me.

**Previou's TextButton code:**

```dart
 TextButton(
 onPressed: cubit.currentIndex != 0
     ? () {
   cubit.decrement();
   boardController.previousPage(
     duration:
     const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
     curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
   );
 }
  :  null,
 child: const Text(
   'Previous',
   style: TextStyle(
     fontSize: 18,
   )),
```

[Here in the light mode everything is okay I wanna show this in dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p5QC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

use `Brigthness` for color

```
 style: TextStyle(
     fontSize: 18,
     color: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark 
            ? Colors.green
            : null,
   )),
```

Comment: Thank you it is work but the color in all onboarding screens become the same color in this case (grey). so I added another condition to work only in the first screen so the function become like this:  TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                                color:  Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark && cubit.currentIndex==0
                                    ? Colors.grey
                                    : null,
                              ),

Comment: Glad i was able to help you.

Comment: Confirm Answer if it solved.

Comment: Sorry, I can't because I do not have 15 reputations!

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use Previous text on first onboarding screen then use following structure :

```
child: FlatButton(
            child: Text(
               currentIndex == slides.length - 1 ? "": "Previous"),)
```

Or if you don't want to use Previous Button on first onboarding screen then use following structure :

```
child: 
     currentIndex == slides.length - 1 ? null :
      FlatButton(
            child: Text(
                "Previous"),)
```